# Builder pattern - Build() method reusability

Tags: c++11, design-patterns, builder, builder-pattern

There is a Builder. Programming language is irrelevant.

Which one is correct:

1. - you set up the builder
   - you are able to call `Build()` as many times you like to. So in result you end up with X objects of the same parameters (or even changed parameters if you add more configuration.
2. - you set up the builder
   - after `Build()` call, the builder has to be set up again to be able build another object.

Is there any convention how should the `Build()` behave?

Both scenarios may be valid. In first scenario you have to copy the values, in second you are able to move the values from builder to created object.

I'd like to properly name the "builders" to be able to distinguish behaviour by just reading the name; code comments are lies, the code always tells the truth.

=== edit

The solution for C++11 is quite interesting:

```
class Builder final
{
public:
    Result Build() &&;
    Result Build() & const; //if you allow building multiple times
};

//... usage:
auto optimized = Builder().Build();
auto builder;
auto copy = builder.Build();
auto optimized2 = std::move(builder).Build();
```

Using variable after `std::move` is mainly assumed as invalid operation (it's in valid, but not determined state until you set a new state of this variable, or you say in type documentation that it's fine to use it)

Comment: What would be the advantage of the second approach?

Comment: Not copying the data if it's used like `OneTimeBuilder`

Comment: What is `OneTimeBuilder`?

Comment: I mean the second approach is optimized to not copy the data if the builder is used only to create one object and after that is destroyed.

Comment: The C++ solution you show looks very nice. Is the specifier `final` important though?

Comment: The `final` for a class is a habit to keep code clean.
In my code inheritance is allowed only for interface implementation, it's not allowed to use inheritance of implementation (there are exceptions only if there is no other clear way to do things)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both ways are valid, with some caveats. It really depends on your purpose. To the outer code, the `build` method only returns an object of the type that the Builder is responsible for creating. However, internally you can create that object right in the Builder's constructor (when you want different instances of the Builder), or you can create the object directly inside the `build` method (I've seen a lot of a static Builders like this).

Through the first option, `build()` always returns a reference to the same object. Through the second one, you get a completely new object every time you call `build()`.

Note, however, that the pattern is flexible enough to do things the other way around - create a new object on every `build` call on a Builder instance, and reuse the same (static) object on a static Builder.

Like I said at the beginning, both forms are valid. It really depends on your domain and purpose.

Comment: The purpose of builder is to returns the new object in both cases. There is only difference if you are able to call Build() multiple times in a row or user has to set up builder every single time one want to call Build().

Comment: Are you talking about your implementation or the Builder in general? The purpose of the Builder pattern per se is to encapsulate complex initialization. If you return a new object every time you call `build` or not is somewhat of an implementation detail that depends on your purpose. So whatever you end up doing still adheres to the Builder pattern as long as you encapsulate creation and initialization logic.

Comment: I'm talking about `Builder` pattern in general.

In theory maybe it's possible to always return the same object, but it has to be protected in such way that changing state on object received by one `Build()` call does not affect the state of other objects returned by `Build()`.
If it does then its something like Singleton Builder.

Comment: Yes, it is possible. But that doesn't even matter :) you asked if there's any convention for the Builder pattern. Clearly I didn't make myself clear in my answer, but what I was trying to say was that the Builder pattern is defined by it's capability of hiding complex (but flexible) creation and initialization logic. As such, the way you choose to actually create, initialize and manage your objects is up to you. People tend to create Builders capable of outputting multiple objects given a set of constraints coded in the Builder class itself, but only because it's the most common use case.

Answer (score 1):

Josh Bloch describes it the first way in *Effective Java*.

> The Builder pattern is quite flexible. A single builder can be used repeatedly to build multiple objects. The parameters of the builder can be tweaked between invocations of the `build` method to vary the objects that are created.

Comment: That makes sense and makes a vote for behaviour `1.`